# How to change href value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this  link `<a href="/Countries/388/10">next</a>`. How can i achive that when i click on next a href to change value to  `<a href="/Countries/388/20">next</a>` without refresh.When user click again to be 30...again 40.... Any ideas? Like counter, to add 10 after click

Comment: What is the point of this, given that once the link is clicked the page will be unloaded? Also, what is the logic - should each successive click add 10 to the final value?

Comment: i want on click to change value ...to add 10 after every click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest method would be to use RegEx:

```
$('a.next').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //Prevent the link from going anywhere
    var href=$(this).prop('href');
    var RegEx = /(.*)\/([\d]+)/g
    var Number=href.replace(RegEx,'$2');
    Number=parseInt(Number)+10
    href=href.replace(RegEx,'$1'+'/'+Number);
    $(this).prop('href', href);
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8690puqf/)

#### UPDATE

Doing this each time the page reloads is better to do with Back-End language you are using (PHP, .NET, etc.), however this should be able to do the trick if it MUST be done with jQuery.

```
$('a.next').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //Prevent the link from going anywhere
    var href=$(this).prop('href');
    var RegEx = /(.*)\/([\d]+)/g
    var URL = href.replace(RegEx,'$1')
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(URL) > -1) { // If this is the current URL
        var Number=window.location.href.replace(RegEx,'$2');
        Number=parseInt(Number)+10
        $(this).prop('href', URL + '/' + Number);
    } else {
        var Number=href.replace(RegEx,'$2');
        Number=parseInt(Number)+10
        $(this).prop('href', URL + '/' + Number);
    }
});
```

Comment: its good example but i need to change value in <a href ="/Countries/388/20">..,<a href="/Countries/388/30"></a> ...

Comment: @None The answer will work, it only has the extra stuff on because of `.prop` which is used because href is a property. If you desperately need it without the whole URL, you can change `.prop` to `.attr`

Comment: kinda ... when i use your example  $('a.next').click(function (event) {
       
          var href = $(this).prop('href');
          var RegEx = /(.*)\/([\d]+)/g
          var Number = href.replace(RegEx, '$2');
          Number = parseInt(Number) + 10
          href = href.replace(RegEx, '$1' + '/' + Number);
          $(this).prop('href', href);
          $("a.next").attr("href",href);
      });
i just change last line of code but it comes to 20 and thats it

this is my link  <a class="next" href="/Countries/388/0">next</a>

Comment: when i click first time in url i get http://localhost:60664/Countries/388/10 second time i get http://localhost:60664/Countries/388/20 but then third time it returns to http://localhost:60664/Countries/388/10

Comment: Kinda? How so? If an answer has helped overcome your problem don't forget to click the tick over to the left of the post.

Comment: i wrote to you what is my problem...after third clicking it returns me to http://localhost:60664/Countries/388/10

Comment: Okay, so something else must be resetting it then I guess? Before the `$(this).prop('href', href);` line, try putting in `console.log(href);` and see what it's spitting out in the console.

Comment: with  event.preventDefault() works fine ... but when i remove it then resetting it...but i need to remove it...so that can redirect me :/

Comment: Got it, okay. If this is doing it after a page load then I would suggest doing this with whatever back-end language you are using and updating it on the page load. I'll try and update my answer with something that would probably work in jQuery. :/

Comment: again something is wrong because now when i click on link <a href="/Countries/388/0">next</a> i get url <a href="/Countries/388/398">next</a> and not <a href="/Countries/388/10">next</a> and second time when i click next i get <a href="/Countries/0/0">next</a>

Comment: @None Must be something you're doing because I've created a [test HTML document](http://pastebin.com/bNmG5kkv) and it's working fine.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('href', '/Countries/388/20');
});
```

You need to use preventDefault() to not to redirect.

And to make it like counter

```
$("a").click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();
var _url = $(this).attr("href");
var _url_start = '/Countries/388/';
var _url_end = parseInt(_url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/"), url.length-1));
$(this).attr('href', _url_start+(_url_end+10)');
    });
```

Comment: If you want to redirect, then what is the point of changing href?

Comment: he wants to change href before redirecting ( AFAIU) , so he still wants the page to go to new location

Comment: @void what about the last lines needs counter.

Comment: @void Rereading his question. all he wants is to change the href. so you're right.(as opposed to other answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $(this).prop('href','/Countries/388/20');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Markup:

```
   <a id="myLink" href="/Countries/388/10">next</a>
```

jQuery:

```
   $('#myLink').click(function() { $(this).attr('href', '/Countries/388/20' });
```

Here, I've given your `a` element an `id` for selecting purposes. The jQuery selects this element based on the `id`, and assigns the new value to the `href` attribute.

This seems like odd requirements, though I have to say.

Answer (score 0):

how about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/1s51vo72/2/)

Code:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    var countarr = $(this).attr('href').split('/');
    var countval = countarr.pop();
    countval = parseInt(countval,10) + 10;
    var url =  countarr.join('/') + "/" + countval;
    alert(url);
    $(this).attr('href',url);
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

remove `e.preventDefault();` if you want to redirect

Comment: i dont want to redirect but when i click few times on next it alert me same value always. always 20

Comment: its working can i just tell how can i call it in my <a href="/Countries/388/10">next</a> because i need to change that value in href :/

Comment: i am not sure of what you are asking.

Comment: <a href="Countries/388">next</a>  when user click first time it appears in my href <a href="Countries/388/10">next</a> , second time <a href="Countries/388/20">next</a>...and so on